# Find Parent EntityKey and Type in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

Is it possible to get the EntityKey and type of an entity's parent entity without knowing the type?  I've tried doing the following

```
public partial class TestEntities
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(logChanges);
    }

    void logChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                                    EntityState.Added | 
                                                    EntityState.Deleted | 
                                                    EntityState.Modified);
        TestEntities context = sender as TestEntities;

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
        {
            if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship && stateEntryEntity.Entity != null)
            {
                Audit audit = new Audit
                {
                    AuditID = Guid.NewGuid()
                };

                foreach (var relationship in stateEntryEntity.RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds())
                {
                    var parent = stateEntryEntity.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<EntityObject>(relationship.RelationshipName, relationship.TargetRoleName);
                    audit.Decription =
                        string.Format("{0} changed on {1} with id of {2}",stateEntryEntity.Entity, parent.GetType().Name);
                }

                context.AddToAudits(audit);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

But I get the following.

```
An EntityCollection of EntityObject objects could not be returned for role name 
'Canine' in relationship 'TestModel.FK_CANINE'. Make sure that the 
EdmRelationshipAttribute that defines this relationship has the correct 
RelationshipMultiplicity for this role name. For more information, see the 
Entity Framework documentation.
```

I'm wondering if maybe I'm approaching this the worng way.

Comment: When you say "Parent", I'm assuming that you mean the 'child' entity is in a one-to-many relationship with another entity and is at the many end.  So you want to know the type at the one end?  Am I understanding properly?

Comment: You stated that correctly.  I want to know the type name and the primary key so I can log the change, "Dog named 'Spot' with id of '1222' changed on Canine with id of '12313'.

Comment: How are you entities created, POCO, T4, by the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search it isn't feasible to do what I wanted with EF. I wanted to crawl the inheritance tree for Auditing purposes.  I ended up creating an Auditor interface that logs an audit message.  I created Auditor implementations for the each EF entity type I wanted to audit. When the calling code asked for a class that implemented the Auditor interface I used named mappings from Microsoft Unity to inject the concrete class or avoid auditing if no mapping was found.